# Where can I find free motion capture footage?

Tags: animation, assets

Are there any repositories of free motion capture footage? Or maybe just libraries of animations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- [Carnegie-Mellon University Graphics Lab Motion Capture Database](http://mocap.cs.cmu.edu/) contains 2548 free human motion captures.
- [Motcap](http://Motcap.com) has lot of free motion capture files in bip and bvh formats.
- [Mocapdata](http://www.mocapdata.com/) has 4199 free motion capture.

[This](http://www.motion-capture-system.com/resources/software.html) & [This](https://sites.google.com/a/cgspeed.com/cgspeed/motion-capture/cmu-bvh-conversion) page contains some more links/info.

You should also check out, [Mixamo](http://www.mixamo.com/)

Comment: I was writing almost the same answer, so I +1 ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can find a lot of free motion capture clips on these websites:

1. [Cgspeed](http://www.cgspeed.com)
2. [Animstreet](http://www.animstreet.com)